# overflow with height auto

Tags: html, css

I was trying to overflow a content that does not fit the parent. But I am not able to.

Here is the code

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="header"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
  <div class="bottom"> 
     <div class="container">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus doloribus beatae iure cum culpa est eum quas nulla adipisci alias iusto ea aut asperiores. Animi nemo quod incidunt ratione voluptatum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.content{
 height:200px;
 width: 100px;
 background:lightblue;
 display:inline-block;  
}

.header{
 background:red;
 display:inline-block;
}
.bottom{
 height:auto;
 display:inline-block;
}
.container{
  height: inherit;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

My [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/5s79bqvb/1/)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want to hide the content that overflows the parent content container, or have it extend to cover the extra content?

Comment: I want to overflow only the .bottom since it is overflowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here - http://jsfiddle.net/5s79bqvb/3/

```
.content{
    height:200px;
    width: 100px;
    background:lightblue;
    display:inline-block;  
     overflow:auto; // you need to set overflow = auto to the parent element 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
Is not possible just to set the scroll only in the .bottom?

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to scroll the hole .content I want to scroll the .bottom only

Answer (score 1):

So you want the text in the blue box to not break out of the blue box?

I've done this a few ways:

1. Set `overflow: hidden` to `.content` OR
2. Set fixed height on `.bottom` OR `.container` and apply `overflow: hidden;` to either.

Comment: Is it possible without fixed height?